# Porting code: is there any API equivalent to utssys() in Linux? I need to port utssys() unix API to Linux environment?

Tags: c

utssys() in unix gives the total numbers of users on a file.Its a undocumented API , there is no manual entry for this API neither in Solaris man page nor in Linux man page.Is there any equivalent API in Linux OR i can use the same in Linux also(I don't know as its undocumented). I googled it also but did not get any info as such.please help.

```
int DU_Utssys_Unix(void* buf, int arg, int type, void* out)
    {
    int result;
    // Perform system-call
    errno = 0;
    if ((result = utssys(buf, arg, type, out)) < 0)
        return result;
    // Look into the result:
    return ((fu_data_t*)outbp)->fud_user_count;
    }
```

above is the piece of code which i need to replace for Linux. Can i use syscall() for finding out the user count on a file. If yes, where it is saved???

In Unix they have below structures to save this info as used in above code snippet, do we have the same in Linux or different ?

```
typedef struct f_user 
    {
    int     fu_flags;       /* see below */
    union 
        {
        struct 
            {
            pid_t   u_pid;
            uid_t   u_uid;
            }u_info;
        struct 
            {
            int     k_modid;
            int     k_instance;
            int     k_minor;
            }k_info;
        } fu_info;
    }f_user_t;

typedef struct fu_data 
    {
    int             fud_user_max;
    int             fud_user_count;
    struct f_user   fud_user[1];
    }fu_data_t;
```

Comment: Your description of what the call does differs quite significantly from http://lists.parisc-linux.org/hypermail/parisc-linux/3585.html

Comment: @NPE is there any API present in Linux for this purpose?

Comment: There is more than one use of [utssys](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/common/syscall/utssys.c?v=OPENSOLARIS). In this case, the OP should be asking for a system call equivalent of 'number of users of a file'

Comment: Please have look on my changed query. I just added code snippet to get more idea of it.Basically its returning the user count of a file.

Comment: @melpomene the purpose is to get the user count on a file in Linux. Above is the code and structures used in Unix for the same. Please give some pointer to do this in Linux. Can we use syscall() to deal with it ??

Comment: @AdeshKumar sometimes there is no direct equivalent so you need to find/implement your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a system call to do this in Linux, but you could, as root, do the following:

- Stat the File getting the `st_dev` and `st_ino` values
- walk the `/proc/*/fd/*` and for each entry:
- if `st_dev` & `st_ino` match then increase the count

Comment: But it seems difficult to use them for implementation. Can't we use syscall() any how to do the same? Can you have any idea of f_user_t and fu_data_t structures ? I mean ,could we use these in Linux as well ? Or we need to find some other way ?

Comment: There **is no syscall** that does the same in Linux. This structure is created specifically for the purposes of implementing this function. Nothing else uses it in the Solaris kernel. I could explain the structures and what they do, but there is no point as it's utterly useless for the purposes of this function as it only uses the length of the list as a return code, which is the number of users of the file. I've given you a reasonable algorithm for emulating it under linux.

Answer (score 0):

int scan_proc(data* fileData, int* Count)

```
{
DIR*           pDir;
struct dirent* dEntry;
int            retCode = 0;
int            dirPattern;

pDir = opendir(".");
if (!pDir)
    {
    return -1;
    }
while ((dEntry = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {
    if (!strcmp(dEntry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dEntry->d_name, ".."))
        {
        continue;
        }

    dirPattern = strtol(dEntry->d_name, NULL, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || dirPattern == 0)
        {
        continue;
        }
    if (chdir(dEntry->d_name) < 0)
        {
        continue;
        }
    retCode = scan_pid_dir("fd", fileData, pCount);
    if(retCode)
       {
       return -1;
       }
    chdir("/proc");
  }
closedir(pDir);
return 0;
}
```